# Max date problem on joined table

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, join, grouping

For the example use date: 03-16-2011 as today's date

table record: record_id, record_status, record_submitted_date

table record_change_log: change_log_id, record_id, new_record_status, record_change_date, old_record_status

(Will only have one record_id)
table record data:

```
1, key, 2011-03-14 08:24:12.04051-04
2, manual, 2011-03-15 09:56:32.04051-04
3, entered, 2011-03-16 07:44:01.04051-04
```

(Will have multiple record_id's and record_change_date's)
table record_change_log data:

```
100, 3, entered, 2011-03-16 09:54:01.04051-04, ''
101, 3, updated, 2011-03-16 09:55:01.04051-04, entered
102, 2, manual, 2011-03-15 09:56:32.04051-04, ''
103, 3, valid, 2011-03-16 10:00:01.04051-04, updated
104, 2, updated, 2011-03-15 10:01:51.04051-04, manual
105, 3, returned, 2011-03-16 10:11:22.04051-04, valid
106, 1, updated, 2011-03-16 11:11:11.04051-04, key
107, 23, manual, ...
108, 100, test, ...
```

What I need is to return all record_id's daily with the last entered change log.
So record_id 1 would return:

```
106, 1, updated, 2011-03-16 11:11:11.04051-04, key
```

and record_id 2 would not be return as the date is not today:

```
104, 2, updated, 2011-03-15 10:01:51.04051-04, manual
```

and record_id 3 would return:

```
105, 3, returned, 2011-03-16 10:11:22.04051-04, valid
```

But in the query I only need the record_id and the new_record_status returned that have changed with today's date, so record_id 2 would not be returned in the results but 1 and 3 would.

Now the other part of the query is I only need record_id's that are in the records table, so these other records in the change log table would not get returned as well:

```
107, 23, manual, ...
108, 100, test, ...
```

So the desired results are as these are the last entries in the change log table as well as they are records in the record table:

```
105, 3, returned, 2011-03-16 10:11:22.04051-04, valid
106, 1, updated, 2011-03-16 11:11:11.04051-04, key
```

I have tried to join the tables but I can't seem to limit the results in the change log table. And I can limit the results in the change log table but not able to select all the records I need would out the GROUP BY complaining about something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could join on a correlated sub_query, comething such as...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  record
INNER JOIN
  record_change_log
    ON record_change_log.change_log_id = (
      SELECT
        change_log_id
      FROM
        record_change_log
      WHERE
        record_id = record.record_id
      ORDER BY
        record_change_date DESC
      LIMIT
        1
    )
```

(I've left the "today only" parts up to you, as I think the "just one record from the change log" is the part you wanted help on.)

Comment: But wouldn't this only return the one record? or does it return one record for each join?

Comment: For each record in the [record] table, the correlated sub_query takes the [record_id] (which is what makes it correlated). The subquery then finds all matching [change_log_id]s, but return only the one with the highest date. This means that there will only ever be one [change_log_id] returned per [record_id] (sometimes that will be NULL, where no matches were found), but the [change_log_id]s will be different for each record in the [record] table.

Comment: Thanks, will have to remember this

Answer (score 0):

```
--
-- Pull today's most recent change log entries for every known "record_id",
-- if any.
--
SELECT *
  FROM record_change_log
 INNER JOIN (
             -- Find the timestamp of the most recent change log entry
             -- for each known "record_id" (in the "record" table),
             -- which change occurred today.
             SELECT record_id,
                    max(record_change_date) as changed
               FROM record_change_log
              INNER JOIN
                    record USING (record_id)
              WHERE record_change_date::DATE = CURRENT_DATE
              GROUP BY 1
            ) most_recent ON most_recent.record_id = record_change_log.record_id
                             AND
                             record_change_date = most_recent.changed;
```

Comment: Question, if I used the record_change_date::DATE = CURRENT_DATE how could I do this for Monthly as well?

Comment: @PhillPafford, you could get this month's by: `DATE_TRUNC('month', record_change_date) = DATE_TRUNC('month', NOW())`.